# LINQ queries give CS8600 and CS1662 warnings in VS2022 and C#10

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2022, nullable-reference-types

Started a new task today of migrating a console app to VS2022 and C#10 and ran into a show stopper that I can't find a workaround for, other than using a compiler directive to suppress the warnings. I'm hoping to avoid that as this app has hundreds if not thousands of LINQ queries that use a similar syntax. Here are the basics of what I've run into.

```
public static class ResponseCodes
{
    public static string MEI0066 => "ME-I0066";
    public static string MEI0069 => "ME-I0069";
    public static string MEI0070 => "ME-I0070";
}

public class DebugLog
{
    public DebugLog()
    {
        this.DebugLogId = null;
        this.LogType = string.Empty;
        this.ResponseCode = string.Empty;
        this.Explanation = string.Empty;
    }

    public DebugLog(int? p_id, string p_logType, string p_responseCode, string p_explaination)
    {
        this.DebugLogId = p_id;
        this.LogType = p_logType;
        this.ResponseCode = p_responseCode;
        this.Explanation = p_explaination;
    }

    public int? LogId { get; set; }
    public string ResponseCode { get; set; }
    public string Explanation { get; set; }
    public string LogType { get; set; }
}

public enum LogEntryTypes
{
    BlackListedIP,
    DNSQuerySuccess,
    DNSQueryFailed,
    WhiteListedIP
}

public class QueryLogs
{
    public QueryLogs()
    {
        this.DebugLogQueue = new List<DebugLog>();
    }

    public List<DebugLog> DebugLogQueue {get;set;}

    public DebugLog? Query()
    {
        DebugLog _debugLog = new DebugLog()
        {
            LogId = 0,
            LogType = LogEntryTypes.DNSQuerySuccess.ToString(),
            Explanation = "IP was valid",
            ResponseCode = ResponseCodes.MEI0070
        };

        DebugLogQueue.Add(_debugLog);

        _debugLog = new DebugLog(1, LogEntryTypes.BlackListedIP.ToString(), "This a test", ResponseCodes.MEI0066);
        DebugLogQueue.Add(_debugLog);

        _debugLog = new DebugLog(2, LogEntryTypes.DNSQueryFailed.ToString(), "This string is not null", ResponseCodes.MEI0069);
        DebugLogQueue.Add(_debugLog);

        // This LINQ query gives a CS8600 warning "Converting null literal or possible 
        // null value to non-nullable type.
        DebugLog returnValue = DebugLogQueue
            .FirstOrDefault(x =>
                (x.ResponseCode == ResponseCodes.MEI0069) 
                && (x.LogType == LogEntryTypes.DNSQueryFailed.ToString()));

        // This form uses the null-coalescing operator but gives CS1662 warning
        // "Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of 
        // the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to to the
        // delegate return type."

        returnValue = DebugLogQueue
            .FirstOrDefault(x => (x.ResponseCode ?? ResponseCodes.MEI0069));

        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

What's been tried:

Because class ResponseCodes is static its values will never be null.

Because the enum LogEntryTypes is converted to a string when used, they'll never return a null value.

As suggested by other posts I've tried the following:

1. Changing static class ResponseCodes to have nullable values by using "static string? MEI0066 => "ME-I0066";"
2. Changing the property getter/setter of DebugLog class to use "public string? ResponseCode { get; set; }"
3. Changing LogEntryTypes to a string const such as dNSQueryFailed = LogEntryTypes.DNSQueryFailed, but that's no different than using the static values from class ResponseCodes.
4. The Query method in class QueryLogs allows a nullable DebugLog to be returned so that it works with the .FirstOrDefault query operator, which doesn't apply to the DebugLog property values.
5. Setting compiler directive to:
   "#pragma warning disable CS8600 // Converting null literal or possible null value to a non-nullable type." eliminates the warning and the code runs, but doing this on hundreds of queries will most definitely come back to bite me later.

So the CS8600 and CS1662 warnings have to be coming from the LINQ side when the property value is emitted and returned, but for the life of me, I haven't been able to come up with the correct syntax to get the query written so that the warning goes away. I'm not even sure where to look any further on this issue.

So am I missing something here or is this a non-starter approach for LINQ queries in C#10?

Comment: What is `.FirstOrDefault(x => (x.ResponseCode ?? ResponseCodes.MEI0069))` hoping to do? FOD requires you to pass a method that returns a bool. `(x.ResponseCode??ResponseCodes.MEI0069)` is not a bool; it's a string that is either the value of `x.ResponseCode` or `ResponseCodes.MEI0069` if x.ResponseCode is null

Comment: As to your CS8600 - what do you want to do if that FirstOrDefault returns `default` into your "not nullable" `DebugLog returnValue` ? e.g., `DebugLog? returnValue = DebugLogQueue.FirstOrDefault(x =>`, `DebugLog returnValue = DebugLogQueue.First(x =>` ...

Comment: .FirstOrDefault(x => (x.ResponseCode ?? ResponseCodes.MEI0069)) is a typo I made and forgot to remove before posting, it can be ignored. As for what I want to do with the DebugLog? returnValue = DebugLogQueue.FirstOrDefault(x => strictly speaking, that's irrelevant and out of context for the question and title of the post.  If you have a suggestion you’d like to make on how to address the default return type of string? in the LINQ queries, that would be something we can all benefit from.

Comment: @DooHickey, the comments made by @CaiusJard are accurate to the code you've posted.  The CS8600 is because `DebugLogQueue.FirstOrDefault(...)` returns `DebugLog?` but you're forcing it into an instance of `DebugLog`.  There are no `string?` as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Jimmy, That is what I was missing, thanks for being direct and to the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most  problems  when using net6, are caused by this new stupid nullable feature of c#. The worst thing is that it is going in new projects by default and the most people spend lots of time trying to find why it sudddenly stoped working or give strange warnings. Just make this small chanage in your net 6 propjects files

```
 <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <!--<Nullable>enable</Nullable>-->
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I just read some more about how to work around this or adapt to it.  I reviewed the code in VS2019 against the code in VS2022, both are the same, but no compiler warning in VS2019. I didn't import the project from 2019 to 2022, I created a new project and copied source files only so as not to bring any customized settings over to VS2022.

Comment: From what I can tell, project settings are the default OOB settings for both 2019 and 2022, so I assume, the warning comes from C#10, perhaps a more literal use of nullable types is now required, which from my chair, is a good thing. Just wasn't expecting something on the first day, to so widely impact the way the code was originally written. This is going to require far more edits than first anticipated.

Comment: you get the personal hero for the day award, that one tip cut warnings and errors from over 5,700 down to just under 2,400. Nice. I can call it a good day, after all, thanks again.

Comment: It's not a "problem" though.. It's a more safe style of programming that makes sense in certain contexts. If there are 5700 warnings and error lights on your dashboard sticking black tape over half of them doesn't mean you solved the root cause of the warning..

Comment: Excellent point and wasn't but I was wanting to get to runtime errors ASAP, which I'm sure to have. This app is all about string manipulation, so it makes heavy use of LINQ queries. And it has several nullable types that show up in those queries. A nullable DateTime was a concern, but I think I'm getting an idea now of how to address those.

Comment: Example for a nullable DateTime? see the last line
List<DebugLog> _smtpDebuglogList = DebugLogQueue.Queue
.Where(x => x.ResponseCode == ResponseCodes.MEI0129 
  && x.LogEntryType == LogEntryTypes.DomainInvalid.ToString() 
  && x.Socket == 0 
  && string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.ConversationType) 
  && (x.MsgDate.HasValue ? (x.MsgDate.Value.Ticks < _lastLogDateTime.Value.Ticks) : false)).OrderBy(x => x.MsgDate).ToList<DebugLog>();

By testing for a value 1st and using an inline if then, sometimes with properly placed parenthesis, you can make these nullable values work as they did before.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. This was nothing but an annoyance and I am not sure they though of legacy apps upgraded to VS2022 and .Net6 when they enabled this feature.